# MVC.JQuery.DataTables - sort not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatables, mvc.jquery.datatables

I am using MVC.JQuery.DataTables Version 1.5.36 in one of my Projects.
I am using the Ajax option to query data from the serverside.

The Controller action to retrieve the data is the following:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllMyTasksTable(DataTablesParam dataTableParam, DateRangeQueryOption queryParameters)
    {
        var currentUser = await UserService.CurrentUser();
        var timezoneOffsetMinutes = UserSettings.UTCOffsetMinutes;
        var tasks = TaskBoardService.GetAllMyTasks(currentUser, queryParameters, timezoneOffsetMinutes).OrderBy(t => t.DueDate).ThenBy(t => t.ListTitle);
        return DataTablesResult.Create(tasks.Select(t => new SPTaskViewModel(t.Id, t.Title)
        {
            ListTitle = t.ListTitle,
            DueDateString = t.DueDateString,
            Status = t.Status,
            Effort = t.Effort,
            WorkUnits = t.WorkUnits,
            TotalWork = t.TotalWork
        }).AsQueryable().Cast<SPTaskViewModel>(), dataTableParam, new ResponseOptions<SPTaskViewModel>() { ArrayOutputType = ArrayOutputType.ArrayOfObjects });
    }
```

The Configuration of the datatable on the client side in JavaScript is this:

```
  function CreateMyTasksDataTable(elementId, url, data) {
    if (tasksTable != null) {
        tasksTable.destroy();
    }
    tasksTable = $('#' + elementId).DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "/scripts/locales/DataTable/@(Model.DatatableLanguageCode).json"
        },
        dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'copy' },
            { extend: 'csv' },
            { extend: 'excel', title: '@Strings.MyTasks' },
            { extend: 'pdf', title: '@Strings.MyTasks' },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                customize: function (win) {
                    $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                    $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                    $(win.document.body).find('table')
                            .addClass('compact')
                            .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                }
            }
        ],
        autoWidth: false,
        pageLength: 50,
        responsive: true,
        ajax: { url: url, type: "POST", data: data },
        serverSide: true,
        searching: false,
        stateSave: true,
        columns: [
                        { data: "Title" },
                        { data: "Id" },
                        { data: "ListTitle" },
                        { data: "DueDateString" },
                        //{
                        //    data: {
                        //        _: "DueDateString",
                        //        sort: "DueDateFileTimeUTC"
                        //    }
                        //},
                        { data: "Status" },
                        { data: "Effort" },
                        { data: "WorkUnits" },
                        { data: "TotalWork" },
                        { data: "Id" }
        ],


        columnDefs: [
                {
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var rowHtml = "<button class='ladda-button btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-3-3 btn-edit' data-style='slide-up' onclick='LoadEditTaskWindow(\"" + row.Id + "\", \"" + row.ListId + "\");'><i class='fa fa-pencil' style='margin-right:5px;'></i> @Strings.ButtonEdit</button>";
                        return rowHtml;
                    },
                    targets: 8
                },
                {
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var rowHtml = '<a href="@Url.Action("Tasks", "TaskBoard")?listId=' + row.ListId + '">' + row.ListTitle + '</a>';
                        return rowHtml;
                    },
                    targets: 1
                },
                {
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var rowHtml = '';
                        if (row.IsNew) {
                            rowHtml = rowHtml + " <span class='label label-success'>@Strings.New</span>";
                        }

                        if (row.Stuck) {
                            rowHtml = rowHtml + " <span class='label label-warning'>@Strings.OnHold</span>";
                        }

                        if (row.IsOverdue) {
                            rowHtml = rowHtml + " <span class='label label-danger'>@Strings.OverDue</span>";
                        }

                        return rowHtml;
                    },
                    targets: 2
                }
        ]
    });
    $('#' + elementId).on('draw.dt', function () {
        stop_laddaButtons();
        init_laddaButtons();
    });
}
```

After I updated from Version 1.3.xx, sorting stopped working.

I can't figure out, what the problem is in my data / configuration, that sorting stopped working.

Has anybody had a similar problem and found a solution?

This is what I see in the JavaScript Object

[image]
And this is the .Net Object in the Controller
[image]

Comment: Hi, I wrote the Mvc.JQuery.DataTables .NET code. Im a bit confused by what you are trying to acheive.

Are you trying to have server-side only sorting? i.e. the client doesn;t control it?

Comment: Hi, I want to do client side sorting. I have updated from Version 1.3.56 to 1.5.36 in my project. After the update, client side sorting didn't work anymore. I have tried many things to get it working again, but I couldn't find out any reason, why sorting stopped working. After I downgraded again, it worked like before. When I click on a column header in the table, using 1.5.36 simply nothing happens. The weird thing is, what does the server side have to do with the client side... Can you reproduce the issue or is it just happening in my project.

Comment: Can you capture the posted data using Fiddler? See if the filter options are being passed correctly.

Comment: Make sure the Datatables version matches the one on the example site- you can see all features working there https://aspdatatables.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint, I'll try as soon as possible and let you know about the result.

Comment: I have tried updating the JavaScripts and CSS plus any Version above 1.3.56, but still no success. Sorting does not work. What could be the problem? In some of the versions I get an exception when the DataTableResult.Create method is called.

Comment: I have updated the Post with Screenshots of the JSON Objbect and the Object in the Controller. It seems like the vaues for sorting are not passed to the controller

Comment: It looks like the model binder hasn't registered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the model binder may not be registered - try adding this:

```
if (!ModelBinders.Binders.ContainsKey(typeof (DataTablesParam)))
                ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof (DataTablesParam), new DataTablesModelBinder());
```

to the startup code (e.g. in global.asax/Application_Start )